# How to install kZenExplorer?

Tags: installation, configuration

I just got an old Creative Zen Micro. I plugged it into the computer, and the system wouldn't acknowledge that there was any sort of device plugged in. Turns out Creative Zen Micros were only made to run on windows systems.

Then I find out that there's this program you can install for Linux systems called KZenExplorer, and it's supposed to enable your system to detect the device and manage it. The package is a tar.bz2 file, and I found out how to install that sort of package, but when I tried to do it that way, it got stuck in the configuration process and had an error that wouldn't let me proceed normally. The website for KZenExplorer mentioned something about required libraries and listed them off. There were only two of them, libnjb and taglib.

I looked up more information and a bunch of people on multiple different forums were talking about how they had to download the libraries, and build the package themselves or something like that. First of all, I have no Idea where to put these libraries, what they do, how to build anything, I really have no clue how to go about doing this at all.

I'm stuck, I'm losing patience. If anyone knows anything about KZenExplorer and how to get it to run on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to know that KzenExplorer is a **KDE** application that makes it possible to transfer tracks to MP3 players that are supported by libnjb. It also allows to manage playlists, create smart playlists and add ratings to the tracks on the player.

KZenExplorer needs the following libraries:

```
libnjb (>= 2.0)
taglib (>= 1.3)
```

To install libnjb:

```
sudo apt-get install libnjb
```

To install taglib:

```
sudo apt-get install taglib
```

After installing the requirments extarct the bz2 archive and go to the directory and issue the following commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```